# Flutter - show items in a list view with just the necessary length and borders

Tags: flutter, listview, border, rounded-corners

In my list view in a Flutter project, I need to show items i.e. pieces of text that are stored in a `List` variable. Each item (i.e. piece of text) will have rounded borders but the length of each item  will vary  according to the number of characters in the text. And on tapping each of the list item i.e. the piece of text, some action will take place.

Following is an image showing how the output should be:

[image: target output]

Currently each list item takes the maximum  size of the  horizontally available space and text is aligned in the middle. But I want the background of each list item to be just containing the piece of text and not to be the full size horizontally and then text should be in the middle of the background.  Current result is in the following image.
[image]

Code:

```
final List<String> names = <String>['Topic 1', 'Topic 2 ', 'Topic 3', 'Topic 4', 'Topic 5'];

ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: names.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 50,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      // color: msgCount[index]>=10? Colors.blue[400] msgCount[index]>3? Colors.blue[100]: Colors.grey,
                      child: Container(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 0,0,0),
                            child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children:[
                              Expanded(
                          child: TextButton(

                            onPressed: () {

                          print("Do something!");

                          },
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                              tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,


                              minimumSize:MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(double.infinity, 14)),
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
                              ),


                           backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                  
                                Colors.white

                              )),

                          child:Text('${names[index]} ',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,


                          ),
                          ),

                          ),
                      ]

                          ),
                          ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              )
```

How can I achieve the list items to be as in the 1st screenshot ?

**EDIT:**
The above list view is inside the following code i.e. the following code should be appended to the above code and necessary brackets should be suffixed.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        // child: Container(
        //   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80, left: 24, right: 24),

        child:Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // or something simular :)
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Select a Topich000'),
```

**EDIT2:**
I am pasting the full code (i.e. not only the list view related code as the list view is inside other code snippet) from my application below.
So when you post answer, make sure that you use the format of my full code below:

```
 final List<String> names = <String>['Topic 1', 'Topic 2 ', 'Topic 3', 'Topic 4', 'Topic 5'];
     return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
            title: const Text('Topics'),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            
            child:Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // or something simular :)
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('Select a Topic'),
                  
                  Expanded(
    
                      child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      itemCount: names.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 50,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                          child: Container(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 0,0,0),
                                child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children:[
                                  Expanded(
                              child: TextButton(
    
                                onPressed: () {
                              print("Do something !");
    
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/subtopicScreen", arguments: {'index_found': index+1,
                                'uploadable_image_path':uploadable_image_path });
    
                              },
                                 // );
    
    
    
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                  tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    
    
                                  minimumSize:MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(double.infinity, 14)),
                                  
                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
                                  ),
    
    
                                  backgroundColor:
                                  MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                      //Colors.green[900]
                                    Colors.white
    
                                  )),
    
                              child:Text('${names[index]} ',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    
    
                              ),
                              ),
    
                              ),
                          ]
    
                              ),
                              ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                  )
                  )
    
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // ),
          ),
    
    
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
            child: Container(
              height: 35.0,
              width: double.maxFinite,
              /*decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0))
              ),*/
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), onPressed: (){ },),
    
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      //Navigator.pushNamed(context, "YourRoute");
    
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>  topicScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: TextButton(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                        child: Text('..',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                // backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                      ),
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.teal,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        onSurface: Colors.yellow,
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal, width: 2),
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print('Pressed');
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
    
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try giving the widget in the `builder` method of the `ListView.builder` widget a height, specifically to your `Container`.

```dart
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  return Container(
    height: 50,
    width: <your width here> <<<<<------
```

EDIT:
Working code.

```dart
final names = <String>[
      'Topic 1',
      'Topic 2 ',
      'Topic 3',
      'Topic 4',
      'Topic 5'
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        title: const Text('Topics'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // or something simular :)
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Text('Select a Topic'),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: names.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              print("Do something !");

                              // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/subtopicScreen", arguments: {'index_found': index+1,
                              //   'uploadable_image_path':uploadable_image_path });
                            },
                            // );

                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                              minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                const Size.fromWidth(100),
                              ),
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    40,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                //Colors.green[900]
                                Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),

                            child: Text(
                              '${names[index]} ',
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        // ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 35.0,
          width: double.maxFinite,
          /*decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0))
              ),*/
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              //IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), onPressed: (){ },),

              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  //Navigator.pushNamed(context, "YourRoute");
                },
                child: TextButton(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: Text('..',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            // backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                  ),
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.teal,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    onSurface: Colors.yellow,
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal, width: 2),
                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('Pressed');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: `width: <your width here>` - list items will have varying width

Comment: my bad, did not quite catch that, use the answer from the top comment :)

Comment: The another answer also did not work

Comment: Give me a minute, let me try it locally.

Comment: waiting for a solution from you ....

Comment: added `EDIT2:`. Make sure your code for the list view fits there.

Comment: Check updated comment.

Comment: What changes did you make ?

Comment: Removed expanded, cleaned up your code a bit, added const everywhere, etc.

Comment: How to add the border now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Expanded widget and remove `minimumSize:MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(double.infinity, 14))` from your TextButton Widget.

Code:

```
ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemCount: names.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                height: 50,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                // color: msgCount[index]>=10? Colors.blue[400] msgCount[index]>3? Colors.blue[100]: Colors.grey,
                child: Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              print("Do something!");
                            },
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                tapTargetSize:
                                    MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
                                ),
                                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    Colors.white)),
                            child: Text(
                              '${names[index]} ',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            })
```

Comment: I remove thed `Expanded` widget and `minimumsize` property and it did NOT work.

Comment: Works for me: https://dartpad.dev/?id=c7a96df0ce6e792a0f704b6a89681178

Comment: dartpad shows the expected output without the border. But in my application it does not work... I am gonna give more code in OP.

Comment: added 'EDIT:' in OP

Comment: See the `EDIT:` part in OP first. I get this error: ' The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.'

Comment: Yeah it's probably because you have a ListView inside a column, both take up all the available vertical space which creates an error. Try wrapping your whole ListView inside an Expanded widget instead of every TextButton individually.

Comment: added `EDIT2:`. Make sure your code for the list view fits there.

Comment: 'Try wrapping your whole ListView inside an Expanded widget instead of every TextButton individually' -  what do you mean ?

Comment: How to give the border color as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and used [**`UnconstrainedBox`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UnconstrainedBox-class.html).

**UnconstrainedBox** means render at its **natural** size.

Your List:

```
    List list = [
    'Science',
    'Mathematics',
    'English',
    'Mental Ability',
  ];
```

Your Widget:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        UnconstrainedBox(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(20.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                print('You Tapped on ${list[index]} subject');
              },
              child: Text(
                list[index],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: On tapping each list item, something is to be done there. Where is the tap handler?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed I update the answer click on subject name and see the tapped subject name on consol

Comment: added `EDIT2:`. Make sure your code for the list view fits there.